# How can I format a UTC TIME in jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datetime, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid.mobile in phonegap.Then I met a problem.I get a json from remote url,such as"**2013-11-11T10:06:27Z**".How can I format it in jqgrid?
Here is my code,but it doesn't work?

```
jQuery('#grid').jqGrid({
     ...
    colNames:['checkin_time'],
    "colModel":[
    {"name":"checkin_time","index":"checkin_time","sorttype":"date","formatter":"date","formatoptions":{"srcformat":"Y-m-d H:i:s","newformat":"m/d/Y"}},
     ],
     ...
```

Comment: Your format is not `Y-m-d H:i:s`. You have additional `T` and `Z` literal characters.

Comment: Yes，it is UTC time.So I don't know how to format. `Y-m-dTH:i:sZ` doesn't work either.

Comment: Because they are **literal** characters, not codes. Does `srcformat: 'ISO8601Long'` work?

Comment: No,I have tried it.The result is same.

Comment: And `c`? (Sorry, I have nowhere to test it myself.)

Comment: I'm afraid.It doesn't work.Nothing shows in the grid.

Comment: Then it's clear that, when the manual says "The definition of the date format uses the PHP conversions", it's not entirely true. Last try: how about `Y-m-d\\TH:i:s\\Z`?

Comment: I am sorry for late reply.I found a mistake in my program.I fixed it and try above ways again.I tried Y-m-dTH:i:sZ,Y-m-dTH:i:sZ,c,Y-m-d\\TH:i:s\\Z.But one is useless.Both of them shows a wrong time,and some of the even show a wrong date.I don't know how to format.Maybe I should change the json date to a string in the background.@ÁlvaroG.Vicario